# Why isn't my background color rule being applied?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the back ground but it wont change can any one give me any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong????

```css
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

main {
  background-color: #D7E3FA;
}

.card {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #FFFFFFF;
}

h1 {
  color: #1B212C;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
p {
  color: #5E636B;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629334994832-2c7fcf7dbf3c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=774&q=80" alt="this is a image of a flowers and a house">

    <h1>Courtney Brown</h1>

    <p>I live In Chicago,Il</p>

    <!-- link tag goes here -->
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">&#127940;</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">&#127947;</a>
      <a href="#" target="_blank">&#9977;</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: You're also missing a closing brace on your `h1` rule. That can break anything that comes after. A good editor that auto-formats your code as you work is critical to avoiding such errors.

Comment: Ok thanks so much guys I appreciate the help it worked! I'm still new but im never gonna give up and look forward to gaining more knowledge from this site

Answer (score 3):

Move these links from your CSS to your HTML :

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also in the `.card` rule, `#FFFFFFF` is not a valid color. You have to remove one `F`.

Comment: Ok thanks so much guys I appreciate the  help it worked! I'm still new but im never gonna give up and look forward to gaining more knowledge from this site.